# Telegram Bot is getting all channel messages

Tags: telegram

I want to create a telegram bot to send updates to the groups/channel in which it is added. I used BotFather to create a bot. However, in `https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOTAPI>/getUpdates`, I'm getting all the messages sent in a channel like this: `"channel_post":{"message_id":59,"chat":{"id":-1001192794322,"title":"Nseindia","username":"nseindia_updates","type":"channel"},"date":1588581996,"text":"AMBUJACEM : Bear\nAPOLLOHOSP : Bullish Reversal\nKOTAKBANK : Bullish\nMOTHERSUMI : Bear"}}`

This is not a problem now, but as time goes, the json file could get very large and could pose a problem.

Is there any way such that I don't get all the messages in the json present in `https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOTAPI>/getUpdates`

Answer (score 0):

you should specify the `update_id` of the latest update you've processed as an `offset` parameter to `getUpdates` to make them(updates with less `update_id`) marked processed and that way they wont come up the next time you call `getUpdates`.

In telegram's [Bot API Docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) it says:

> By default, updates starting with the earliest unconfirmed update are
>   returned. An update is considered confirmed as soon as getUpdates is
>   called with an offset higher than its update_id.